# symfony2 cache/log permission issues

Tags: php, apache, caching, symfony, permissions

I've just uploaded a simple symfony2 app on a production server, and I get this configuration error:

```
2 MAJOR PROBLEMS
Change the permissions of the "app/cache/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
Change the permissions of the "app/logs/" directory so that the web server can write into it.
```

editing "app/console", "web/app.php" and "web/app_dev.php" with: umask(0000) doesn't work, and if I right click on that folders with FileZIlla, their permissions are already 777. And so?

thanks...

Comment: Do you have shell access?

Answer (score 0):

You need to recursively set the permissions, most likely.  I'm guessing FileZilla has that option, if not, ssh into the box, and run (replacing /path/to with the actual path)

```
sudo chmod 777 -R /path/to/app/cache
sudo chmod 777 -R /path/to/app/logs
```

Sidenote: setting the permissions to 777 is usually a really bad idea.

Comment: I don't downvote this, but if setting permissions to 777 is (not usually, every time) a bad idea, you should never suggest it

Answer (score 0):

`umask(0000)` doesn't actually increase the permissions available to the script. It just ensures that files & directories created by those scripts are accessible from both the command line and the web server. If you're not using the command line, you probably don't need it at all.